# Reading from 'map' in Firebase DB into ListView in Flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, flutter-layout

I have been trying to read data from a map in my Firebase database to display it in a ListView in my first Flutter app. I've unsuccessfully tried several ways to achieve this. I've gotten to where it at least displays something but it's all bunched in one row of the list.

```
body: StreamBuilder(
        stream: Firestore.instance.collection('Users').snapshots(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (!snapshot.hasData) return Text('Loading data.. Please wait');
          return ListView(
            children: snapshot.data.documents.map<Widget>((document) {
              return new ListTile(
                title: new Text(document['Group'].toString()),
              );
            }).toList(),
          );
        }
      )
```

The map in my db:
[DB screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jozox.jpg)

That results in this:
[emulator screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0mdlb.jpg)
Please can someone help me build my awesome Flutter app.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? Currently you are iterating over your Users collection. You want to iterate over your Group map inside each User?

Comment: Hi Rodolfo. Yes, exactly. So if you look at the DB screenshot, I want to display the following: 

First
Fourth
Second
Third

along with their boolean values

Answer (score 0):

To iterate over a `Group` map inside each `User` you would need to do retrieve your Users collection first:

```
List users = List();
final docs = await Firestore.instance.collection('user').getDocuments();
docs.forEach((doc) {
 users.add(doc.data)
});
```

Then you would need to iterate over that list in your view, similar to this:

```
ListView.builder(
  itemCount: users['Group'].length
  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
    return Text(users['Group'][index].toString());
  }
```

If you wish to use the StreamBuilder, I believe you have to change your `Group` map to a subcollection.